# Ionic Auth Redirect Issue for Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, ionic-native

I'm working to implements the oidc authentication with AzureAD in a ionic project. We use the plugin https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2. After setup based on the instruction, we got issue during redirect.

- For Android:
  It shows the "Can't not match any routes.The url segment msauth"
- For IOS:
  It shows "Safari can't open the page because the address is invalid"

Here are related configurations:

1. AzureAD setup:
   Two platforms:
   android with the bundle id,signature hash and redirect url msauth://[bundleid]/[hash]
   ios with the bundle id and redirect url msauth.[bundleid]://auth

2.For android
Add below config to manifest file

```
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data android:scheme="msauth" android:host="${bundleid}" android:path="/${hash}" />
         </intent-filter>
```

3.For ios
Add below to info.list

```
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>bundleid</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

4.Then the auth code

```
appId: {clientid},
      authorizationBaseUrl: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`,
      scope: "openid offline_access email https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read", // See Azure Portal -> API permission
      accessTokenEndpoint: token endpoint,
      responseType: "code token",
      pkceEnabled: true,
      logsEnabled: true,
      web: {
          redirectUrl: `website url`,
          windowOptions: "height=600,left=0,top=0",
      android: {
          redirectUrl: "msauth://bundle/signature",// See Azure Portal -> Authentication -> Android Configuration "Redirect URI"
          handleResultOnNewIntent:false,
          handleResultOnActivityResult:true
        },
     ios:{
        redirectUrl:msauth.bundleid://auth
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

if you are using ionic capacitor you prolly using angular as well... there are module design for angular and built components to handle.. just put / to redirect back to angular route component i think... i havent tried yet